# Optimizing runtime of comparing 2 Pandas datasets

Tags: python, pandas

I have this issue where I take the 2009/2010 dataset of white house visitors, a csv with these headers.

https://obamawhitehouse.archives.gov/files/disclosures/visitors/WhiteHouse-WAVES-Key-1209.txt

I want to extract the name of all names of visitors who visited in both 2009 and 2010.

I have this function to do this, but it is far too slow.  Is there a conceptually faster way to do this?

```
def task3():
    culled_data = data[["NAMELAST", "NAMEFIRST", "TOA", "TOD"]]
    data9 = culled_data[culled_data["TOA"].str.contains("2009", na = False)]
    data10 = culled_data[culled_data["TOA"].str.contains("2010", na = False)]
    unique_names = pandas.DataFrame({'count':\
    data.groupby(["NAMELAST", "NAMEFIRST"]).size()}).reset_index()
    unqiue_names = unique_names[unique_names["count"] > 1]
    count = 0
    for index, row in unique_names.iterrows():
         if data9[data9.NAMELAST == row["NAMELAST"]].shape[0] > 0 and data10[data10.NAMELAST == row["NAMELAST"]].shape[0] > 0 and data9[data9.NAMEFIRST == row["NAMEFIRST"]].shape[0] > 0 and data10[data10.NAMEFIRST == row["NAMEFIRST"]].shape[0] > 0:

         count += 1

    else:

        unique_names = unique_names[unique_names.NAMELAST != row["NAMELAST"]]

    return count, unique_names
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use python [sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html):

```
fullnames9  = set([' '.join(r) for r in data9[['NAMEFIRST', 'NAMELAST']].values])
fullnames10 = set([' '.join(r) for r in data10[['NAMEFIRST', 'NAMELAST']].values])    
names_who_visited_in_both_years = fullnames9 & fullnames10  # set intersection
```

Note that if two different people have the same first and last name, this code will falsely conclude that they visited in both years. Also, this only gets full names. Getting the DataFrame indexes of people who visited in both years would be more useful, and is left as an exercise ;)